# "Мусорить на землю" — правильно ли сказано?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли будет сказать "Мусорить на землю"? Разве не просто "мусорить" или "бросать мусор на землю"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мусорить не куда, а где. Мусорить можно на улице, в помещении и т.д. Или, как Вы совершенно правильно написали, просто мусорить. А вот куда — это действительно "бросать мусор".
Так что Вы мыслите совершенно правильно.

Comment: вот я так и думала, ура! спасибо вам!

Comment: Не за что. Всегда рады помочь)))

Answer (score 3):

У меня нет полной уверенности в невозможности "мусорить куда". 
Насколько понимаю, слово "мусорить" - относительно недавнее, образовано по анологии с сорить, и вот это самое "сорить" вполне себе встречается в подобном варианте.

Речка текла, ровно бы мохом укрытая, мокро всюду сделалось, заблестели листья, хвоя, комки цветов, гибкие тальники сдавило сыростью, черемуха на том берегу перестала ***сорить в воду*** белым, поределые, растрепанные кисти полоскало потоком, и что-то было в этой поздно, тощо и бедно цветущей черемушке от современной женщины, от ее потуг хоть и в возрасте, хоть с летами нарядиться, отлюбить, отпраздновать дарованную природой весну. [Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
Приспел, не заставил себя долго ждать первый утренник, оглушил инеем гнус, искрошил мелкую траву, на свет выпросталось всякое тыкучее растение с мохнатым семенем, стало -***сорить на землю*** пухом, на кустарниках засветилась листва, до красноты ожгло бруснику в тундре, посыпалась остатная голубика, черника, раскисла поздняя морошка, княженица уронила в кочки последние мелкие ягодки, листья багульника свернулись туже в трубочки. [Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Comment: > У меня нет полной уверенности в невозможности "мусорить куда"

Возможность есть. Но вряд ли это является лит. нормой или благозвучным сочетанием. К тому же, как правильно замечено, парадигма управления у слов сорить и мусорить отличается.

Comment: Я говорил и говорю только о нормативной возможности. Иначе разговор был бы изначально бессмысленным.

Насчет "парадигма отличается" - можно поподробнее?

Comment: мусорить (где? на чем?), сорить (куда? на что?) - по-моему, разница есть.

Comment: Вы это называете "парадигмой управления"?  
Ну да ладно, суть в том, что вы утверждаете эту разницу, а потом на основании своего утверждения её же и доказываете. Я, естественно, никак не могу согласиться, ибо предполагаю, что управление и сочетаемость у глаголов как раз _**одининаковы**_.   

А где это было "правильно замечено"?